# remove windows desktop focus

Tags: c#, .net, winapi

We have a requirement in our application to remove the focus from the Desktop. For instance when i cick on a folder in the desktop the folder gets the focus( it could be Desktop background focus too) . Now in my application i would like to remove that focus programatically when some event occurs. Is anybody aware of any WIN API or a Dotnet class which could do this job for me.

thanks

Comment: What kind of app is this? How could your app have focus **and** the desktop have focus?

Comment: *Something* has to have the focus. Do you want your application to hog the focus and prevent the desktop from ever receiving it? What about other applications (other than yours and the desktop)?

Comment: It is a offscreen render and the operating system does not have control over the screen.

Comment: ...what? I don't think I understand that. What operating system *doesn't* have control over the screen? That's kind of the point of an OS. *What* is an offscreen render? It appears that your scenario is quite unique, meaning that you'll need to provide a lot more details in your question.

Comment: I think Nuetrino wants to make an application such that when it is executing the user should not be able to interact with the desktop ... if this is the case then i think a full screen application should do the task ...

Comment: Due to some classified content i could not reveal the whole stuff. my bad. I was able to figure out this to some extent and found the problem to be the following. I am using a windows form to do some functionality by keeping it invisible. now If i loose the application's focus after launching it i am not able to get it back since the form is invisible. Any ideas? Currently i minimized the form making it visible and get the focus and then making it invisible again which i feel is just a work around. Any other ideas?

Comment: So, you want to force focus back to your app on the firing of a certain event(in your application?), keeping the user from interacting with other windows/desktop?

Comment: I am using a windows form object to implement a functionality. but my form should not be visible at any time. at certain instances I loose focus of the application. Now bringing back the focus to the application is the problem. Since without the form being visible u cannot get the focus to the form. I tried workarounds like minimizing it making the form visible, getting  back the focus and making it invisible once again. But I want some concrete solution where I can be sure the focus is with the application ( when some event occurs ).

Comment: So, I'm not sure how helpful you'll think this is, but I have to say it anyway. Have you considered that using a Windows Form may not be the best design for your application, considering that it should never be visible yet should always have the focus? Windows Forms are for client-based apps, and it's awfully hard to use them *without* their being visible. What you're trying to do is simply not what they are designed for, and as a result, you'll always have trouble. You might get your car to fly through the air using a rocket booster, but it's not recommended. Try a Windows Service instead.

Comment: I am using a webbrowser control for some funtionality which needs a user environment which is a form in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand your question but if you mean that you want a window to show so that you cannot select (set focus) to the desktop then you would call the ShowDialog method of your window if you're using WPF.

If you're not using WPF, then search for whatever paradigm you need followed by show modally or modal.